# Android TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText with outlined border and show hint text above outlined box

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText for my user input in my app, But now we need different design as like below screen. I mean hint text should be above outlined box instead of within outline border. I did tried few ways but unable to figure exact attribute or style that help me to achieve this kind of UI.

- Expected UI:

[image: Expected UI wireframe]

- Current UI:

[image: Current UI]

- Styles:

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutAppearance"parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
         <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke_color</item>
         <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">
             @style/TextInputLayoutMaterialThemeRoundedShapeAppearanceOverlay
         </item>
         <item name="hintTextColor">@color/hint_color</item>
         <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/hint_text</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="TextInputLayoutMaterialThemeRoundedShapeAppearanceOverlay" parent="">
         <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
         <item name="cornerSize">@dimen/_8sdp</item>
    </style>
```

I am not sure if this is something achievable by style or need to develop custom control with combination of TextView and TextInput controls.

Comment: This is not supported in Material Design themes or styles, nor the Material Design Widgets, you're going to have to roll your own implementation unfortunately. Depending on whether you need animations or not, it shouldn't be _super hard_ to achieve (last famous words) since you can intercept the focus change, get rid of the hint (so it's not animated up) and then make visible the "new hint" at the top.